# How to use proxy in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have Angular proxy wih this settings:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4200",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

So, I have tied to proxy all request to server from `http://localhost:4200` to `http://localhost` without port 4200.

Why it does not work for me?

Command is:

```
ng serve --proxy-config
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is it erroring, is it not proxying?

Comment: it is not proxying, all backend request comes to `http://localhost:4200` instead `http://localhost/`

Comment: Depending on the operating system, look for the npm global configuration file, for example in windows C: /Users/JuanPablo/.npmrc and in that file write the following:
proxy = protocol: // host: port
https-proxy = protocol: // host: port /

Comment: I use windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration will proxy:

```
from: http://localhost:4200/api
  to: http://localhost:4200/
```

So that proxy works outside of Angular, and you would call that URL like this:

```
httpClient.get("http://localhost:4200/api")
```

The above would actually call `http://localhost:4200/` instead. We can shorten this to a call of `httpClient.get("/api")` since we're at the same `domain:port`

> So, I have tied to proxy all request to server from http://localhost:4200 to http://localhost without port 4200.

You'll need a different proxy URL

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

The above configuration will proxy:

```
from: http://localhost:4200/api
  to: http://localhost/
```

The `/api` is dropped from the proxy rewrite by the `pathRewrite` rule.

You would still call `httpClient.get("/api")` to hit the target proxy.

See the documentation here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Proxy is not proxing,

Comment: @OPV could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @OPV it is the `ng serve` that will handle the proxy. The Angular application has to send the HTTP request to the `ng serve` for it to be proxied. This is a server side feature. So you will see the traffic as not proxied in the web browser, but the response will come from the proxy. If it is failing, then make sure the proxy target is working correctly and accessible by `ng serve`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your tag `"/ api /"` to `"/ api / *"` and `"target": "[http: // localhost: 4200] (http: // localhost: 4200)"`.

Make sure you have this in your package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "ng serve -o --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```